# Bios и установка Windows 7

Tags: windows, bios, windows-7, установка

Хочу установить ОС через биос, не выходит нечего.
В boot поставил свой dvd-rom на 1, после перезагрузки чёрный экран и "_" моргает вверху.

**Обновление**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Может, диск с ОС испорчен.

Comment: А еще может быть (раз уж это 7 винда), то биос работает в режиме UEFI, а диск без правильного загрузчика.

Да, версия биоса 1 27 обычно ни о чем не говорит.

Comment: ОС впорядке, в биосе я немогу найти режим UEFI, чтобы изменить на другой, его там попросту нет, я уже все возможные варианты перепроверил, 3 ОС проверил. Я через биос не могу даже на загрузку винды выйти.

Comment: В общем, тебе необходимо произвести проверку:

Диска CD-ROM

Привода CD-ROM

Comment: Винда стояла вчера, дисковод работал, диски читал.

Comment: [Посмотрите, вы все делали аналогично статье ][1]


  [1]: http://itbc.kiev.ua/kak-pereustanovit-windows-7-instrukciya.html

Comment: Погуглил, посмотрел видео, Всё сводится к UEFI, но у меня в биосе его нет.Я в замешательстве, остаёться пробывать через флешку.

Comment: Если все исправно и диск и привод, значит проблема в настройках BIOS.
Какой у вас вариант:
[ЭТО][1]
[ИЛИ ЭТО][2]


  [1]: http://motherboards-reviews.com/ASUS/socket_AM3/M2N68-AM_PLUS/images/ASUS_M2N68-AM_PLUS_BIOS_boot_device_priority.jpg
  [2]: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19273-01/html/821-0243/figures/BIOSBootDevicePri.png

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Вот нашел по вашему биосу [видео](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HlmV2rfHa_g), у парня все получилось (версия, думаю, не критична).

Comment: Посмотрите внимательней на мои скрины, у меня в bios вообще такого нет, он какой то с маленькими функциями, нет не USB Legacy, не UEFI, ничего нет.

Comment: У меня bios insydeH20 Rev. 3.5 а на видео Rev 3.7

Answer (score 1):

F12 - там бут-меню. Т.е. при включении удержи Ф12 - появится меню загрузки - там и выберешь свой дивидюк. Не грузится этот - попробуй любые загрузочные диски - ливэ-сиди, хирэн... та их уйма в природе, с флэшки попробуй "заехать"...

Ага - там ещё, смотрю,  SATA mode  - АНСI - поиграйся с ним, поставь IDE или Compatable какое-нибудь.

Т.е. дифференцировать надо-ть: кашу - отдельно, мухи - отдельно, а тогда уже копать дальше.

Удачи!

У-да-чи!!!